# Calling Visual Studio Excel add-ins from Excel 2007

Tags: visual-studio, excel, vba

I am very new Visual Studio (just downloaded version 2010 Professional), but I believe this is the right way to do web services in excel.

Have created a Excel 2007 Add-In called TestAPI within Visual Studio containing just one class ThisAddIn, the 2 default StartUp and Shutdown procedures and 2 functions I have written myself, say f1 and f2.

When I start Excel 2007 and check Excel Options i can see it as a COM add in, but how can I see these 2 functions within VBA? Any references to either ThisAddIn or TestAPI or f1 or f2 all fail, yet if I put something into the StartUp functions this will automatically be executed whenever I start Excel, which I do find quite annoying. It seems that COM Add-ins are switched on/off at Excel level whereas I cant seem to find the TestAPI anywhere on my list on References (where I could check or uncheck it as required depending on Excel sheet).

I am probably missing an (or multiple) point(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Stubbs has some information on calling VSTO UDFs from VBA on [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2004/12/31/344964.aspx).

Alternatively, you could try building a more vanilla COM add-in for Excel, as described by [Eric Carter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx).

My personal preference for creating user defined functions is to use [ExcelDna](http://exceldna.typepad.com/).

Comment: Thanks, made some progress based on above (key bit was adding the ComVisible), so I can now see the and use the functions. Still dont know how to expose a user defined type (class or structure). Trying to mirror the function stuff doesnt work in vba (wont even compile) since everything seems to be done at run time through objects.

Comment: Above are very useful links. I found that for my purpose I am better off to just create a class library dll and add as a reference where required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared F1 and F2 Public? In the class ThisAddin

```
Public Shared Function F1(x as Object) as Object
  Return x*2
End Function
```

(I'm not sure if Shared is required in VSTO, I use Addin Express, VSTO is such a pain)

Comment: Already had declared functions as public. Shared doesnt seem necessary if ComVisible is set correctly.